# How to avoid two foreach loops and assign conditionally property value from one to another?

Tags: c#, linq

Hi I have the following code, which is working fine.But I am sure there must be more elegant way of doing it through LINQ, like List.Join() or Intersect(),Except() something like that.

```
foreach (var item in itemList)
{
    foreach(var product in productList)
    {
        if(item.Id == product.Id)
        {
            item.LastDate = product.StartDate;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Depending on how you create these, perhaps creating one as a dictionary would be better.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, agreed that assign part might have to be done as is. But I was hoping if the inner foreach loop can be made more efficient,i.e., instead of going one by one,find the first or default and then assign.

Comment: @Llama, in my situaion I can not create a dictionary, will have to use the lists as is, as its an old code and refactoring is not feasible now.

Comment: Are products distinct? (Only one instance of an id in the list ?)

Comment: Under the hood LINQ usually doesn't do anything special as well. [```Join```](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/5697c29004a34d80acdaf5742d7e699022c64ecd/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#L695) for example iterates over the list and creates a ```Grouping``` for each item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, don't use LINQ to modify something but to determine what you want to modify. In this case you could use following `Join`:

```
var toUpdate = from item in itemList
               join product in productList
               on item.Id equals product.Id
               select (Item:item, Product:product);

foreach(var itemAndProduct in toUpdate)
    itemAndProduct.Item.LastDate = itemAndProduct.Product.StartDate;
```

There's a difference to your loop though, you update also all items, but you stop trying to find a matching product when you have found one(because of the `break`). The `Join` above finds all matching and the last one wins. Don't know if it makes a difference though, depends on your data.  You could achieve the same with a `GroupBy`, but it adds complexity maybe for no reason.

Comment: Thanks @TimSchmelter, I actually need to pass the 'toUpdate.Item' to different function for separate processing,am not able to do that. Basically is there any way to access toUpdate.Item ?

Comment: @user2948533 You just need to pass the items? You can pass them for example as list: toUpdate.Select(x=> x.Item).ToList()